# react project on domain shows a blank page

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, web, directory

i am making a website for front end only and with react, i dont have any backend, so to put it on my domain i ran npm run build and tested it locally, it only worked when i started the server from the same directory, so that might be it, but it worked when i started the server from the same directory. Then i went to put it on my domain storage, but when i tried to open it it just shows a blank page. i heard i should set the homepage in react, but i already have a homepage with pure html and i wanted this on a seperate page. I dont think the problem is with my domain, because my main website worked. I think it might be because of the same thing that happened locally, that it is not on the same directory as the main page, my domain is [name].com and i want this page as [name]/learning/main/japanese.html or something like that. is there any way to solve this. I am a begginer so please can you explain it more specifically how to do it, and also sorry if this question is stupid.

this is my app.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import FlashcardList from './FlashcardList'
function App() {
  const [Flashcards, setFlashcards] = useState(HIRAGANA_FLASHCARDS)
  return (
    <FlashcardList flashcards={Flashcards} />
    );
}
const HIRAGANA_FLASHCARDS = [
  //bunch of data
]
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

shuffle(HIRAGANA_FLASHCARDS);
export default App;
```

and my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "flashcards",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"  
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }

}
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is your homepage written in pure HTML already? And is this App.js connected to that HTML page?

Comment: @Gowtham yes it is written in pure html and css and no javascript, but there is multiple pages in pure html except that which the main page has links to

Comment: If you want another HTML page that uses react other than your already existing pages, then you have to link a new HTML page with your redirection link ("/japanese.html") to the main HTML page. The react needs to point to an element in this new HTML page. Correct me if my intrepretation of your question is wrong.